# Wireless earphones suitable for playing? (low latency)

Tags: headphones, latency

I bought a bluetooth earphone but it got ~1 sec delay which is annoying all the time except when listening to music.

What wireless technologies do you recommend instead of bluetooth? (which can be connected to my notebook)

Comment: Product recommendations are actually off-topic here. Are you asking what kind of technology you should look for in wireless monitoring that's no bluetooth?

Comment: Kinda but in the amateur scene. A relatively cheap, low latency wireless technology which can be paired with a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

The pros (and many amateurs) us [*wireless in-ear monitoring systems*](https://www.sweetwater.com/c1044--In_Ear_Monitor_Systems).

They are available in a range of prices from USD 200 or less up to thousands of dollars depending on features and sound quality.

Some major manufacturers include Shure, Sennheiser, and Audio-Technica, all of which are equally respected for their microphones and headphones.

Comment: Those are too professional for me. I just want want a reliable, low latency, not flashy wireless listening device which can be paired with my notebook.

Comment: @Tudvari Low latency costs money. Your options are spend money to lower the latency or have higher latency.

Comment: Re-write 'wireless' as 'wired' then.  It's not as if you're going to be THAT far from your screen when doing something where latency matters.  My cheap Bluetooth headphones also allow a cable to be used. Choose whichever connection is appropriate for the job at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Look at 'in ear monitors' designed for live use.  Latency is typically 5ms on budget systems.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the latency is more from a lower powered notebook so a different connection, even wireless IEMs might not fix it.

If you have no noticeable latency with a wired connection then they do make cheaper RF headphone adapters that you plug into the headphone jack. (I sometimes use them when mixing from my iPad)

The best way to be able to monitor your playing is to get an interface with a direct output and connect your headphones to that.